# Mongodb aggregate get the expired records by using the epoch current timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```json
    { 
      "id" : "58", 
        "topicHeader" : {
            "replayData" : {
                "messageDateInms" : NumberLong(1649448201357), 
                "messageDelayInms" : NumberLong(600000)
            }
        }, 
      "status" : "IN_PROGRESS"
    },
    
    { 
      "id" : "59", 
        "topicHeader" : {
            "replayData" : {
                "messageDateInms" : NumberLong(1650220023677), 
                "messageDelayInms" : NumberLong(600000)
            }
        }, 
      "status" : "IN_IROGRESS"
    }
```

i need to get the expired records based on  current epoch timestamp i.e.
`(topicHeader.replayData.messageDateInms + topicHeader.replayData.messageDelayInms) <= epoch current timestamp`

I am able to resolve by using find() but trying to find better solution so it wont cause any performance issue:

```js
    db.getCollection("col1").find
        ({
            $expr: {
                $lte: [{ "$add": ["$topicHeader.replayData.messageDateInms", "$topicHeader.replayData.messageDelayInms"] }, 1650226443611]
            }
        })
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just saw you have an existing solution after posting my answer. How are your 2 fields populated? Is it possible to create the summed field at one shot when populating the 2 fields? In this way, you can index the summed field for performance. Based on current context, I believe you/me already figured out the most performant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$add` to sum up the 2 fields. Use `$toDate` to cast them into `date` field and compare with `$$NOW`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $lte: [
          {
            $toDate: {
              "$add": [
                "$topicHeader.replayData.messageDateInms",
                "$topicHeader.replayData.messageDelayInms"
              ]
            }
          },
          "$$NOW"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/62EydMggRg7) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you very much...i was unable to find how to use current timestamp ie. new date()  in aggregate. but your answer is very neat. once again Thank you!!

Comment: Hi Ray, one more question, do you know how can i convert the above command in Spring mongoTemplate format?

Comment: @Vineet sorry but I am not an expert in spring... Consider asking a new question for that.

Comment: sure. thank you